# How to add new target environment in eclipse che?

Tags: codenvy, eclipse-che

I'm trying to add a target environment using Eclipse Che on Codenvy.   After choosing "Edit Targets...", it shows me a dialog box containing the instruction **Press the '+' button to create a new target**, but I see no '+' buttons to press.   Is this a bug or have I missed something to get it to populate the list of target environments?

[image: codeenvy screen shot]

```
Codenvy Version :4.6.2
Revision :2ed2377676d10a45
Build Time :2016-08-09 14:39:35
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codenvy's hosted offering at beta.codenvy.com is based on Eclipse Che so you'll see some references to Che documentation below.

Adding a target is used to add a physical device (like an IoT board) to Eclipse Che. The fact that there's no "+" is a bug and I've added it here (https://github.com/codenvy/codenvy/issues/646) - thanks for calling this out. BTW, you can interact with engineers on our GitHub repos:

- Eclipse Che: https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues
- Codenvy Enterprise: https://github.com/codenvy/codenvy/issues

However, if you're trying to build/run your project in the runtime then you'll need to create a command (https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/commands).

Or, if you're trying to create a custom runtime then take a look at (https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/recipes).

Comment: OK, thanks.   IoT board isn't what I was looking for.  It seems like adding a target could be useful for different language runtimes (i.e. adding a Node.js target environment to a project implemented mostly in Java.   ANTLR4 for example has runtime tests of ported runtimes to a number of language environments.   This makes developer setup for contributing to the project tricky because it depends on setting up multiple runtimes on a single dev box.

Comment: Ah, I see - the way you'd do that is by creating a multi-machine environment. So one machine can be Java, another Node, etc... It's all part of implementing a compose-like syntax. You can see the enhancement request here: https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/1527

In the meantime, perhaps you can add the node and Java infrastructure to the same runtime and then just send artifacts to the different areas of the filesystem to have them loaded in the right infrastructure. Commands can help here: https://eclipse-che.readme.io/docs/commands

Comment: I trust you are right that this is "part of implementing a compose-like syntax", but the terminology is Greek to me.   It seems like the docs are using machine, environment, and runtimes as synonyms which a bit confusing.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - machine, environment and runtime are related, but not exactly synonyms.

An environment is the set of infrastructure needed to run the project. The environment can be made up of 1+ machines running 1+ runtimes. The machines in our case are Docker containers and each runs a set of infrastructure that we call the runtime. So if I have two machines, one with tomcat and one with mysql then the environment is the networked combination of the two separate machines and each machine is executing it's own runtime (tomcat or mysql).